# Technical Question - Hyperledger Fabric - Error: error getting endorser client for invoke: endorser client > failed to connect to

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am unsure of this is suitable for this forum as this is a technical question. I will add it anyway to see if anyone has any technical skills here.

I am running fabcar from Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 and the invoke works from the invoke.js program but fails using the CLI and peer chaincode. I have tried a few combinations without any success.

The command -

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile ~/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ~/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ~/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["createCar","CAR300", "VW", "Polo", "Grey", "Mary"]}'
```

Error -

```
Error: error getting endorser client for invoke: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup peer0.org1.example.com: no such host"
```

Docker containers:

```
86b85d99b510/dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_4-2561b83e10218324c7c566345c50373c5f0b501c961992264dc7fa321eaa5f7f/

f0725155e976/dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar_4-2561b83e10218324c7c566345c50373c5f0b501c961992264dc7fa321eaa5f7f/

e2e33a38f61b/peer0.org2.example.com/7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp

a59f7011af8c/peer0.org1.example.com/0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp

f395bed7101d/couchdb1/4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp

b3b7b94ed872/couchdb0/4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp

db56371abe59/orderer.example.com/0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp

ddcabab0b13c/ca_org2/7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8054->8054/tcp

d7b2bd0a94bc/ca_orderer/7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9054->9054/tcp

e0e300be2273/ca_org1/0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp
```

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for technical questions. Most of us, if not all, present here have technical skills.

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799114/in-fabric-first-network-example-hot-to-fix-the-error-transport-error-while-d

Answer (score 0):

This situation is happened because you called a gRPC to peer server but your call failed to hit the server. This situation may happen for many reasons, but for most of the cases the situation is happened due to server down(peer server exit or down due to misconfiguration) or for wrong certificate or your call failed to hit the server due to misconfiguration.

Use "docker container ls -a" to see all containers including the exited one.

Comment: This works now, basically I had to reset all the env vars.